# Symfony and apache

Tags: html, css, symfony

Hi I have done some HTML and put it into a Symfony 3.3.10 installation
The Controller is this

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/",name="Home")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function HomeAction(Request $request){
        return $this->render(":home:home.html.twig",[
            "title" => "MioDerma SPA Ritual Stress Control"
        ]);
    }
}
```

The Issue That I have is That the nav and features are not working my html is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% block seo %}{% endblock %}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=David+Libre|Hind:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block styles %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/reset.css") }}"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/style.css") }}"> <!-- Resource style -->

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="cdå-auto-hide-header">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>
    <nav class="cd-primary-nav">
        <a href="#cd-navigation" class="nav-trigger">
            <span>
                <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
                Menu
            </span>
        </a> <!-- .nav-trigger -->

        <ul id="cd-navigation">
            <li><a href="#0">The team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Our Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Shopping tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- .cd-primary-nav -->
</header> <!-- .cd-auto-hide-header -->

<main class="cd-main-content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</main> <!-- .cd-main-content -->
{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if( !window.jQuery ) document.write('<script src="{{ asset("js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js") }}"><\/script>');
</script>
<script src="{{ asset("js/main.js") }}"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

The .htacacess is this

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

y have extended the base template and I havent made it work on the url the path when i hit the menu is as follows

```
http://localhost:8000/#cd-navigation
```

and my stylesheet is this

```
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Hind", sans-serif;
  color: #25283D;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #8F3985;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

1. Auto-Hiding Navigation - Simple

-------------------------------- */
.cd-auto-hide-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.is-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo {
  left: 5%;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .logo a, .cd-auto-hide-header .logo img {
  display: block;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
  /* vertically align its content */
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #25283D;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger span {
  /* vertically align inside parent element */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em {
  /* this is the menu central line */
  margin: 6px auto 14px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon top line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
          transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after {
  /* this is the menu icon bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em {
  /* transform menu icon into a 'X' icon */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* rotate top line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::after {
  /* rotate bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cd-primary-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul a {
  /* target primary-nav links */
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  color: #25283D;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul a:hover, .cd-primary-nav > ul a.active {
  color: #8F3985;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-primary-nav {
    /* vertically align its content */
    display: table;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul {
    /* vertically align inside parent element */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* reset mobile style */
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul a {
    /* reset mobile style */
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}

.nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
.cd-primary-nav ul:target {
  /* 
    show primary nav - mobile only 
    :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
  */
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
  .cd-primary-nav ul:target {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

2. Auto-Hiding Navigation - with Sub Nav

-------------------------------- */
.cd-secondary-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}
.cd-secondary-nav::after {
  /* gradient on the right - to indicate it's possible to scroll */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  background: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
.cd-secondary-nav.nav-end::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul, .cd-secondary-nav li, .cd-secondary-nav a {
  height: 100%;
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul {
  /* enables a flex context for all its direct children */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.cd-secondary-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /* do not shrink - elements float on the right of the element */
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
}
.cd-secondary-nav li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.cd-secondary-nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .6;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.cd-secondary-nav a:hover, .cd-secondary-nav a.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav ul {
    /* reset mobile style */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav li {
    /* reset mobile style */
    float: none;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
        -ms-flex-negative: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a {
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #8F3985;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

3. Auto-Hiding Navigation - with Sub Nav + Hero Image

-------------------------------- */
.cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}
.cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
          transform: translateY(-60px);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
    top: 80px;
    /* fixes a bug where nav and subnab move with a slight delay */
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 #25283D;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-80px);
            transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main content

-------------------------------- */
.cd-main-content {
  padding: 60px 5% 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cd-main-content.sub-nav {
  /* to be used if there is sub nav */
  padding-top: 110px;
}
.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero {
  /* to be used if there is hero image + subnav */
  padding-top: 0;
}
.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero.secondary-nav-fixed {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.cd-main-content p {
  max-width: 1024px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font-family: "David Libre", serif;
  color: #a5a8a9;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-main-content {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero.secondary-nav-fixed {
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
  .cd-main-content p {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
}

/*
    adjust the positioning of in-page links
    http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/
*/
.cd-main-content.sub-nav :target::before,
.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero :target::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav :target::before,
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero :target::before {
    margin-top: -70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Intro Section

-------------------------------- */
.cd-hero {
  /* vertically align its content */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(../img/cd-hero-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.cd-hero .cd-hero-content {
  /* vertically align inside parent element */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero {
    height: 400px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-hero {
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe I have to correct something in my ht access to make it work properly on a flat non Symfony environment and on older Symfony versions works good it is working perfectly what it could be please help?

Comment: **That the nav and features are not working** did you assign a job for them, did you create a contract with them?are you paying them the right salary?

Comment: sarcastically speaking what do you mean by **That the nav and features are not working**

Comment: I have done everything correctly, I just wanted to know why it didn't worked, or what do I have to change

Comment: what do you mean by **That the nav and features are not working**

Comment: This the broken one https://ibb.co/meRSgR and thisis how it should be working https://ibb.co/g1tUvm

Comment: what do you mean by **This the broken one**?

Comment: you problem has nothing to do with php/.htaccess but with your css/style

Comment: So what should I correct?

Comment: you css, from what i can tell you are using a dropdown similar to a bootstrap dropdown

Comment: Yep, I dunno why i when i call the id via href is not working

Comment: what do you mean by **why i when i call the id via href is not working**

Comment: For example i when i Click the menu to amke work it should work via ID and in other symfony enviroment is working so what could  the mistake that im doing

Comment: i don't understand, right now the menu item go to `#0` which is the same page

Comment: I think I have made it, but still testing

Comment: basically what it happens is that out of the symfony enviroment is not reading some styles out of it or on anterior version it is!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the menu button on desktops:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-trigger {
  display:none;
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Hind", sans-serif;
  color: #25283D;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #8F3985;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

1. Auto-Hiding Navigation - Simple

-------------------------------- */

.cd-auto-hide-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.is-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo {
  left: 5%;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo a,
.cd-auto-hide-header .logo img {
  display: block;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
  /* vertically align its content */
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #25283D;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger span {
  /* vertically align inside parent element */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em {
  /* this is the menu central line */
  margin: 6px auto 14px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon top line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after {
  /* this is the menu icon bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(6px);
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em {
  /* transform menu icon into a 'X' icon */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* rotate top line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::after {
  /* rotate bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cd-primary-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.cd-primary-nav>ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cd-primary-nav>ul a {
  /* target primary-nav links */
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  color: #25283D;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.cd-primary-nav>ul a:hover,
.cd-primary-nav>ul a.active {
  color: #8F3985;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-primary-nav {
    /* vertically align its content */
    display: table;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav>ul {
    /* vertically align inside parent element */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* reset mobile style */
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav>ul::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav>ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav>ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav>ul a {
    /* reset mobile style */
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}

.nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
.cd-primary-nav ul:target {
  /* 
    show primary nav - mobile only 
    :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
  */
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
  .cd-primary-nav ul:target {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

2. Auto-Hiding Navigation - with Sub Nav

-------------------------------- */

.cd-secondary-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}

.cd-secondary-nav::after {
  /* gradient on the right - to indicate it's possible to scroll */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  background: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.cd-secondary-nav.nav-end::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cd-secondary-nav ul,
.cd-secondary-nav li,
.cd-secondary-nav a {
  height: 100%;
}

.cd-secondary-nav ul {
  /* enables a flex context for all its direct children */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.cd-secondary-nav ul::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.cd-secondary-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /* do not shrink - elements float on the right of the element */
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.cd-secondary-nav li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.cd-secondary-nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .6;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.cd-secondary-nav a:hover,
.cd-secondary-nav a.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav ul {
    /* reset mobile style */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav li {
    /* reset mobile style */
    float: none;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a {
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #8F3985;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

3. Auto-Hiding Navigation - with Sub Nav + Hero Image

-------------------------------- */

.cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}

.cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
  transform: translateY(-60px);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
    top: 80px;
    /* fixes a bug where nav and subnab move with a slight delay */
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 #25283D;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-80px);
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Main content

-------------------------------- */

.cd-main-content {
  padding: 60px 5% 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-main-content.sub-nav {
  /* to be used if there is sub nav */
  padding-top: 110px;
}

.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero {
  /* to be used if there is hero image + subnav */
  padding-top: 0;
}

.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero.secondary-nav-fixed {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.cd-main-content p {
  max-width: 1024px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font-family: "David Libre", serif;
  color: #a5a8a9;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-main-content {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero.secondary-nav-fixed {
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
  .cd-main-content p {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
}


/*
    adjust the positioning of in-page links
    http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/
*/

.cd-main-content.sub-nav :target::before,
.cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero :target::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav :target::before,
  .cd-main-content.sub-nav-hero :target::before {
    margin-top: -70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Intro Section

-------------------------------- */

.cd-hero {
  /* vertically align its content */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(../img/cd-hero-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cd-hero .cd-hero-content {
  /* vertically align inside parent element */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-hero {
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .nav-trigger {
    display: none;
  }
  }
  .logo {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<header class="cdå-auto-hide-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>
  </div>
  <nav class="cd-primary-nav">
    <a href="#cd-navigation" class="nav-trigger">
      <span>
                <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
                Menu
            </span>
    </a>
    <!-- .nav-trigger -->

    <ul id="cd-navigation">
      <li><a href="#0">The team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Our Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Shopping tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- .cd-primary-nav -->
</header>
<!-- .cd-auto-hide-header -->
```

Comment: what style are you talking?

Comment: This the broken one ibb.co/meRSgR and thisis how it should be working ibb.co/g1tUvm

Comment: on symofny is noy working out of it is working perfectly